# Costs of fatigue damage - need some statistical data / USA, Europe, Asia

Tags: statistics, fatigue

I am looking for (pretty current/actual) statistical data related with Fatigue damage in machines, Annual fatigue costs in industry (for example with refference to Gross Domestic Product), time evolution of material fatigue damage costs in the USA or in Europe, China, Poland or worldwide. Everythink related with that topics will be helpful.

This data is very hard to find, thats why i decided to post this question. Maybe some of you can help and recommend sites that can be really helpful - i am interested mainly on checked and free access sites. Where can i get statistics about fatigue/fracture damage in machines related to recent years?

Comment: Check out pressure bulkhead in Boeing.

Comment: I dont understand? I dont need one component, but rather sum of damage costs in industry per year. Something like that :)

Comment: It was on event that really put the understanding of fatigue onto the engineers map... However, If you think we will do your research for you then you are on the wrong site.

Comment: I do not expect doing research for me. But thanks for trying to 'help' anyway.

Comment: "fatigue/fracture damage" these are 2 very different things, but there is no source for this data regardless.

Comment: yeah i know, but i am interested in both things though

Comment: I would also be interested in answer to this question, but I don't think it can be realistically answered. Equipment failure is not something companies would want to talk about openly, which I think is even worse when it comes to associated costs.

Comment: What do you want the answer to be ? The bulk of failures are not analyzed,  Or someone knowledgeable looks at the fracture , says "that is fatigue" and no report is needed unless there were significant repercussions.